# How to add aop for non-spring, jersey rest services

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, jersey-2.0

Hi can anyone please tell me how to add aop on normal jersey rest service or any web application without spring.

I have tried it with this [link](http://ganeshghag.blogspot.in/2012/10/demystifying-aop-getting-started-with.html) but it didn't work. In this case I have added aop.xml in META-INF. But still it is not detecting the class which I have added with @Aspect annotation. Please can anyone help me out.

I am working with InteliJ IDE and my code sample as follows.

```
 @Aspect
public class MySimpleLoggerAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.koderzlab.lawman.services.*.*(..))")
    public Object myTrace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("myTrace:before call "
                + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName()
                + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

        Object retVal = "it is an aspectJ sample";
        return retVal;
    }

}
```

And my aop.xml is as follows

```
<aspectj>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="com.koderzlab.lawman.aop.MySimpleLoggerAspect"/>
</aspects>
```

I have added aop.xml in artifact as follows WEB-INF/META-INF/aop.xml
but aspect class is not executing before going to service

Comment: How are you building your application? Providing an aop.xml is only half the job. You'll also need a weaver to interpret it: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html

Comment: Did you add the parameter -javaagent:path/to/aspectj\aspectjweaver.jar to your VM args?
And the path to aop.xml should be WEB-INF/classes/META-INF (in my case, nothing else worked. maybe this is also your issue)
And also - would be good to add to your aop.xml the line:
<weaver options="-verbose -debug -showWeaveInfo"/> to see whats happening

Comment: how did you resolve this if you were able to